# How do I traverse the DOM to slideToggle an element?

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I am trying to get the sub-unordered-list to slide down when I select a link but can't seem to get it work.obviously, I need it to target on (this) as I will have many sub ul's.

- About

  - Our Services
  - Logistics

```
$('nav ul li').addClass('show-icon');
$('nav > ul li').on('click', function (e) {
     $(this).toggleClass('open-sub').find('ul > li ul').slideToggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change your selector to this:

```js
$('nav ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).toggleClass('open-sub').find("> ul").slideToggle(200);
}); //---this should also be changed----^^^^^
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
li a {
  color: blue;
}
.open-sub > a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" title="">Our Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" title="">Logistics</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="">Logistics Services1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="" title="">Logistics Services2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

This selector `$('nav > ul li')` just bind the `click` event for direct child of nav element. Instead you should bind on each `li` elements.

If the code speaks then this selector `$('nav > ul li')` would shout:

1. Get each nav elements.
2. Find the first level `ul` element.
3. Bind the event on `li` elements of the found `ul`.

Comment: This is what is freaking me out as nothing gets added to the sub ul?

Comment: can't get you. @Al-76